# Extract elements of R data frame given their indices

Tags: r, dataframe

I have 2 vectors, x and y, which hold the x and y coordinates (row and column positions) of a data frame, df, respectively. I would like to put the values in df that are associated to those positions in another vector, result, and am wondering there is any way to do this efficiently.

In my example, the positions would be (1,1), (1,4), (2,3), and (4,3). Result is my expected output.

As an example:

```
x <- c(1,1,2,4)
y <- c(1,4,3,3)
df <- data.frame("1"=c("a","b","c","d"),"2"=c("e","f","g","h"),"3"=c("i","j","k","l"),"4"=c("m","n","o","p"))
result <- c("a", "m", "j", "l")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `cbind` the two vectors of position and use it to subset the dataframe.

```
x <- c(1, 1, 2, 4)
y <- c(1, 4, 3, 3)

df[cbind(x, y)]
#[1] "a" "m" "j" "l"
```